# How do i change the footer?

Tags: footer

I downloaded a free theme and I changed everything except the footer I can't change it.
I opened the file **footer.php** and there was only written as shown:

```
</div><!-- /content-wrapper -->
<div id="footer"><?php wp_footer(); ?>
<ul id="footer-nav">
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1' ); ?>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I can not find a way to change the `wp_footer ();`.
Did there is an external file that I need to change?

Comment: ps. sorry for my bad english

Comment: This question will be nearly impossible to answer without some information: what Theme, specifically, did you download (also helpful: where did you get it), and what footer content are you trying to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wp_footer()` function is a WordPress hook.  It allows plugins to place additional content at the bottom of the page - this is very useful if you're installing tracking scripts like Google Analytics.

But that function is *not* what is adding copyright information or other junk usually bundled with free themes.

Instead, look in the theme's `functions.php` file.  There's likely a function somewhere in there that's outputting the content you see.  You'll also see somewhere this line:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'some-function-name' );
```

That line will fire the `some-function-name()` function whenever WordPress calls `wp_footer()`.  Just delete that line and you should clean your footer up.

Answer (score 0):

```
function footerchange() {
echo "What you want to Display";
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'footerchange' );
```